# In android app, how to load 3d animations at runtime for augmented reality?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm making an application with augmented reality and I need to load at runtime a 3d animation (in a .fbx file). Is it possible to use arcore to load this animation and display to the users ?

Comment: It can be slow loading, so depending on your content, you have to do some load-balancing while its playing. There is no general purpose algorithms for this like there is for shoveling video...

Answer (score 0):

Your fbx file should have animation, you can check in .sfb file animation array.
While you rendering the 3d model you can use that animation and play.

```
 val modelData = it.getAnimationData(0)
                    val modelAnimator = ModelAnimator(modelData, it)
                    modelAnimator?.start()
```

Full code:

```
 ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(fragment.context, model)
            .build()
            .thenAccept {
                val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
                val skeletonNode = SkeletonNode()
                skeletonNode.localScale = Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f)
                skeletonNode.setParent(anchorNode)
                skeletonNode.renderable = it
                skeletonNode.setOnTapListener { hitTestResult: HitTestResult, motionEvent: MotionEvent ->
                    listener.onClick()
                }
                anchorNode.setOnTapListener { hitTestResult: HitTestResult, motionEvent: MotionEvent ->
                    listener.onClick()
                }


                it.material.setTexture("baseColor", texture)
                fragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
                val count: Int = it.animationDataCount
                if (count > 0) {
                    val modelData = it.getAnimationData(0)
                    val modelAnimator = ModelAnimator(modelData, it)
                    modelAnimator?.start()
                }

            }
            .exceptionally {
                return@exceptionally null
            }
```